# Word suggestion Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, search, autocorrect

I'm looking for some help with coding a word suggestion system using Python.
On given input of a random sequences of characters I want to be able to search through a wordlist and give some recommendations of words.

The closets thing I have found was is a spelling correction system (https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) when analysing the function "edits1" it does produce some results however this is based on one edit (e.g. including one 'a' to the input string).

What I want to achieve is using more than one letter i.e. vowels or consonants.
e.g. given the letters 'prt' the dictionary search should recommend 'part' and 'apart' etc.

## Filler.py - https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

```
            import re
            from collections import Counter

            def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())

            WORDS = Counter(words(open('E:\\new\\words.txt').read())) #wordlist containing numerious word e.g. 'prut', 'prot', 'port', 'part', 'prat', 'pert', 'pret', 'apart'.

            def candidates(word): 
                "Generate possible spelling corrections for word."
                return (known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known(edits2(word)) or [word])

            def known(words): 
                "The subset of `words` that appear in the dictionary of WORDS."
                return set(w for w in words if w in WORDS)

            def edits1(word): 
                "All edits that are one edit away from `word`."
                letters    = 'aeiouxyz'
                splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 2)]
                inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in letters]
                return set(inserts)

            def edits2(word): 
                "All edits that are two edits away from `word`."
                return (e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1))
```

## InputString.py

```
            import filler

            h = ['prt']
            for x in h:
                input = filler.candidates(h[0])
                print(input)
```

Comment: Well, the `filler.py` is based on two or less edits and more edits may be easy using a loop. The question is, how many times edit do you want and are you sure that consonants are also used to insert, say, e.g. given 'bt', 'but', 'bat', 'beat' should be recommanded while 'belt', 'breakfast' and so on are also recommanded?

Comment: Up to four edits would fulfil my requirements. Only the vowels and consonants that are specified in the 'letters' variable are to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have your code modified. The `Suggestor` class receive two parms, which are `max_times` and `letters`, so that you can change them whenever and whatever you want.

```
import re

from collections import Counter

def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())

WORDS = Counter(words(open('big.txt').read()))

class Suggestor:
    def __init__(self,max_times,letters):
        self.max_times = max_times
        self.letters = letters

    def candidates(self,word):
        return self.known(self.edited_word(word))

    def known(self,words):
        return set(w for w in words if w in WORDS)

    def edit(self,word):
        letters = self.letters
        splits = [(word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 2)]
        inserts = [L + c + R for L, R in splits for c in letters]
        return list(set(inserts))

    def edited_word(self,raw_word):
        words = [[raw_word]]
        for i in range(self.max_times):
            i_times_words = []
            for word in words[-1]:
                i_times_words += self.edit(word)
            words.append(list(set(i_times_words)))
        return [w for word in words for w in word]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    word = 'prt'
    suggestor = Suggestor(max_times=4,letters='aeiouxyz')
    print(suggestor.candidates(word))
```

And the output of the above test is:

> {'partie', 'parity', 'purity', 'part', 'port', 'proto', 'porto', 'party', 'apart', 'parait', 'export', 'operate', 'expert', 'pirate'}

Moreover, my suggestion is checking the probabilities of all the words and you may filter some of them with Bayes' Theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I was looking for! :)